# How do I associate a certificate with an IoT Edge SDK connection on iOS & Android

Tags: certificate, mqtt, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-sdk

I am trying to connect to an IoT Edge device from iOS and Android apps.  It looks like the SDK relies on using the local device certificate store to enable the handshake/authentication for connecting to MQTT.

I have this working on Windows using a local store but don't know how to programmatically add certificates to a store on Android or iOS, or present a cert to bypass the need to instal locally.